# Does playframework 1.x handle cross site scripting (xss)?

Tags: playframework, xss, playframework-1.x

I'm using the playframework with version 1.2.5 and I have just a simple Question.

If I use for example:

```
public static User findByUsername(String username) {
    return User.find("username = ?", username).first();
}
```

So if I perform this call, does the "JPAQuery find()" or the playframework prevent cross site scripting and such things?

If not, what do I have easily to do for preventing it in all my database interactions?

Thanks a lot.

Cheers,

Marco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cross-site scripting does not quite apply to the code you posted, so I suppose you mean SQL injection. In that case, the code you posted should be safe. (The wrong way would be to build the query by concatenating Strings with `+` operator.)

See here: http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.5/security#sql

Answer (score 0):

Since version 1.0.1, Play’s template engine automatically escapes string.
More details on this page: [playframework owasp top 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6382900/playframework-owasp-top-10)

Comment: In addition to this dont forget to check if its enabled in the application.conf file with "future.escapeInTemplates=true". See here http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.1.1/security